# VBA - Adding columns using find

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add 2 columns using find and I'm getting an error.

```
 .Columns(Rows(1).Find("Eot")).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

This was the original code:

```
 .Columns("I:J").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This inserts two columns to the left of the column with the found value:

```
.Rows(1).Find("Eot").EntireColumn.Resize(, 2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Answer (score 2):

you're missing the `Column` property of the `Range` object (return by `.Find` method) to return a column index number and feed it to `.Columns()` collection

```
.Columns(rows(1).Find("Eot").Column).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```